# Python Scipy get sides of a 3D convex hull

Tags: python, scipy, geometry, delaunay

I used `Scipy Delaunay` to compute the 3D convex hull of a set of points, and I'd like to get **a list of all its external sides** (triangles defined by 3 points), anybody knows how to get that information?
Thanks

code:

```
import scipy.spatial
import numpy as np
import csv
"""loading colors"""

colors = np.array([(XYZRGB(rank, name, X, Y, Z))
                  for rank, name, X, Y, Z in csv.reader(open('colorshort.csv'))])

"""doing geometry"""

tri = scipy.spatial.Delaunay(colors[:,[2,3,4]], furthest_site=False)
# Delaunay triangulation
indices = tri.simplices
# indices of vertices
vertices = colors[indices]
# the vertices for each tetrahedron
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `help(tri)` you'll see a list of all the attributes of `tri`. I think the attribute you are looking for is `tri.convex_hull`, which gives the indices of the points belonging to the convex hull. So to get the actual vertices you would use

```
colors[tri.convex_hull]
```

Comment: Now, [you got 2 problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) @adrienlucca.wordpress.com !